# Oracle PL/SQL: how the SYSDATE is different from 'DD-MMM-YY'?

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, date, plsql

I'm wondering how come `SYSDATE` is different from, let's say `28-APR-18` (assuming that `SYSDATE` is April, 28 of 2018).

I was debugging a little script I made, and got plenty of errors. After a while I managed to narrow it down to how the tables were filled (they were filled using the literal '`DD-MMM-YYYY`' method and I was comparing against `SYSDATE`).

To understand, I wrote the following to see how each compares:

```
declare var1 DATE; var2 DATE;
BEGIN
   var1 := SYSDATE;
   var2 := '27-APR-18';

   if var1 = var2 then
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('oh yeah');
   else DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WTF?'); 
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SYSDATE);DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('27-APR-18');
   end if;
END;
```

If the above is ran, I get the following (which is getting me puzzled):

```
WTF?
27-APR-18
27-APR-18


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Since they are both declared as DATE type, shouldn't they both be equal?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Oracle, a `DATE` value - despite the name - contains a time part as well. `SYSDATE` contains the current date **and** the current time (up to seconds).

The Oracle tools by default (stupidly) hide the time part of a `DATE` value. If you run:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as sysdate
from dual;
```

you can see that.

So `SYSDATE` might be `2018-04-27 09:15:42` whereas the string (!) constant `'27-APR-18'` is silently converted to a `DATE` value at midnight: `2017-04-28 00:00:00`

More details in the chapter [Basic Elements of Oracle SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#sthref117) in the manual

---

If you don't care about the time part, you can use `trunc()` to set the time to midnight, `trunc(sysdate)` yields `2018-04-27 00:00:00` (if today is `2018-04-27`). Note that `trunc()` does not "remove" the time, it only sets it to 00:00:00

---

Unrelated, but:

You should never rely on implicit casting between strings and other non-character types which `var2 := '27-APR-18'` does - it would e.g. fail on my computer as my default NLS date format is different.

If you need a `DATE` value, then specify a proper date literal:

```
var2 := DATE '2018-04-27';
```

or

```
var2 := to_date('27-APR-18', 'dd-mon-rr');
```

or

```
var2 := to_date('27-APR-18 00:00:00', 'dd-mon-rr hh24:mi:ss');
```

Comment: I personally agree we should show the time by default, but majority of users apparently don't care to see the default midnight time portion of their data.

Comment: Awesome! That really explains why, and I was also wondering how to display the full date which you already mentioned. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: I disagree: the majority of users (including Dan V) is confused that the display shows `28-APR-18` but a select with `where xxx = to_date('28-APR-2018', 'dd-mon-yy')` doesn't return any rows.

Comment: Beside above you should prefer 4-digit year instead of 2-digit `RR`. Otherwise you will fall into trouble latest in 2050.

Comment: This fails to discuss the fundamental difference that `SYSDATE` has a `DATE` data type but `'28-APR-18'` is not a date but is a text literal (with the properties of both `CHAR` and `VARCHAR2` data types). You also fail to mention the effect `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` has on `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( SYSDATE )`.

Comment: @MT0: You did see the "*whereas the string (!) constant '27-APR-18' is silently converted to a DATE*" part?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what @horse has explained, you may use `TRUNC` on `sysdate` for var1 and date literal on `var2` in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, it would match.

```
declare 
var1 DATE; 
var2 DATE;
BEGIN
   var1 := TRUNC(SYSDATE);
   var2 := DATE '2018-04-27';

   if var1 = var2 then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('oh yeah');
   else 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WTF?'); 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SYSDATE ||','||'27-APR-18');
   end if;
END;

oh yeah
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code (with line numbers)

```
 1 DECLARE
 2   var1 DATE;
 3   var2 DATE;
 4 BEGIN
 5   var1 := SYSDATE;
 6   var2 := '27-APR-18';
 7 
 8   if var1 = var2 then
 9     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('oh yeah');
10   END
11     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WTF?'); 
12     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SYSDATE);
13     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('27-APR-18');
14   END IF;
15 END;
```

**In line 5**: `'27-APR-18'` is a text literal (not a `DATE` data type) and when you try to assign it to a `DATE` varaible Oracle will try to be helpful and implicitly cast it to a `DATE` using the `TO_DATE( date_string, format_model )` function. Since this is an implicit cast then Oracle will use its default format model which is the user's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter.

You can see the format of the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter using the query:

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

And line 5 is the equivalent of:

```
var2 := TO_DATE(
          '27-APR-18',
          ( SELECT VALUE
            FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
            WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
        );
```

If the default format model matches the string then this implicit cast will work - otherwise your code will raise an exception.

The other possible problem is where the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-YYYY` (or an equivalent) and then `27-APR-18` will be cast to the date `0018-04-27 00:00:00` and have a (probably) unexpected and wrong century!

*(Note: `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is a session parameter so each user can set their own value so you should **NEVER** rely on implicit casts otherwise you will find that the same code which is working for yourself fails for other users or can even fail for the same user in different sessions - without your code ever changing.)*

What you should do in line 5 is either use a `DATE` literal or explicitly cast the text literal using the `TO_DATE` function with a format model:

```
var2 := DATE '2018-04-27';
var2 := TO_DATE( '27-APR-18', 'DD-MON-RR' );
```

**In line 8**: You are comparing two date; however, the `DATE` data type always has a time component and unless you run the code at 2018-04-27T00:00:00 then `SYSDATE` will have a "non-zero" time component whereas `var2` did not have an explicitly specified time component so the implicit cast will have given it a time component of `00:00:00` (midnight). This means that, except for at exactly midnight, the two will never be equal and the comparison will return `FALSE`.

If you want to zero the time components of a `DATE` when you are comparing two dates then use the `TRUNC()` function or specify a range, like these:

```
IF TRUNC( var1 ) = var2 THEN
IF var2 <= var1 AND var1 < var2 + INTERVAL '1' DAY THEN
```

**In line 12**: This is the reverse of line 5 - `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( string )` takes a string argument - not a `DATE` - so Oracle will implicitly try cast the `DATE` to a string (using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` again). So line 12 is effectively;

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
  TO_CHAR(
    SYSDATE,
    ( SELECT VALUE
      FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
      WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
  )
)
```

Since your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-RR` this is not displaying the time components and is not showing you why the variables are different.

If you do:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

DECLARE
  var1 DATE;
  var2 DATE;
BEGIN
  var1 := SYSDATE;
  var2 := DATE '2018-04-27';
  -- or var2 := TO_DATE( '2018-04-27 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' );
  -- or var2 := TIMESTAMP '2018-04-27 00:00:00';

  if var1 = var2 then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('oh yeah');
  END
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WTF?'); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( var1 );
    -- or DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TO_CHAR( var1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( var2 );
    -- or DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TO_CHAR( var2, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then the output will be:

```
2018-04-27 10:28:59
2018-04-27 00:00:00
```

and you can see the difference.